# C - History of commands (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, file, ubuntu

I am trying to remove the line 20 of `file1`. The rest of the program is a simple shell that is working only I can not make the history of commands used by the user.
The error message that I have when I try to insert a command is: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

The code that I am executing is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define GetCurrentDir getcwd  //get the path of file
#define BUFFER_LEN 1024

int ch;
FILE *file1, file2;
char line[BUFFER_LEN]    

while(1){
    if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin))
    {                       
        break;              
    }
    else if(line, BUFFER_LEN, SIGQUIT){
                fopen("fileOne.c","r");
            while((ch = getc(file1)) != EOF){   
                printf("%s",ch);
            } 
        } 

        if(count<20)
        {
            fputs(argv[100] ,file1);  
        }
        else{
            fclose(file1);
            file1 = fopen("fileOne.c","r"); 
            rewind(file1);        
            file2 = fopen("repicla.c","w"); 
            while((ch = getc(file1)) != EOF){              
                if((ch = getc(file1)) != "\n"){         
                    count++;            
                    if(count != 20){                
                    putc(ch, file2);            
                    }
                }   
            }   
            fclose(file1);  
            fclose(file2);  
            remove("fileOne.c");    
            rename("replica.c","fileOne.c");    
            fputs(argv[100] ,file1);   
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) `fopen("fileOne.c","r");` --> `file1 = fopen("fileOne.c","r");`, `printf("%s",ch);` --> `printf("%c",ch);`. BTW Can this be compiled?

Comment: It can be compiled, and still with the same error

Answer (score 1):

Most significantly, **I can't compile your code!** I'll delve into that shortly, but I suspect with major errors like the ones in your code, you need a different book because whatever book you're reading (you *are* reading one rather than *guessing*, right?), that isn't working out too well for you. Have you considered K&R2E?

**My compiler emits error messages**, and so will yours. It's possible that you're trying to execute a stale binary which we can't help you with. You need to make your code *compilable*.

Assuming that issue is fixed, you have an error in the following code, which **your compiler is likely to warn you about**:

```
while((ch = getc(file1)) != EOF){   
    printf("%s",ch);
}
```

You're passing an `int` corresponding to the `%s` format delegate to `printf`. You need to pass a `char *`. If you pass the wrong type, you get undefined behaviour, and this is likely to cause a crash.

In this case, I think you might have intended `putchar(ch);` or `printf("%c",ch);`.

Nonetheless, **when your compiler yells at you about something, DO NOT IGNORE IT!** If you don't understand the error or warning, *ask a question about that, instead*!

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
int ch;
```

This line is undefined behavior:

```
printf("%s",ch);
```

`%s` is the format for a nul-terminated string.  But `ch` is an `int` value, so the `printf()` code almost certainly treats the passed `int` value as an *address* and tries to use it as the starting address of a nul-terminated string.

That's a pretty sure-fire way to force a core dump from a `SIGSEGV`.